# Algorithm to seat people at tables given who they would like to sit next to

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to devise an algorithm to seat people at a table. The basic premise is as follows:
Given a list of $n$ tables, each with a different number of seats (e.g. $2, 4, 4, 5$), and a dictionary of who a person would like to sit next to:

- Person A wants to sit next to Person B and Person C.
- Person B wants to sit next to Person A and Person D.
- ...

Maximise the number of people seated at the same table with as many people on their preferred list as possible.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be solved with algorithms common in graph matching problems. Are you in a regular setup? or an online setup where people arrive one at a time and must be seated irrevocably?

Comment: @user206904 for the purposes of the problem, assume all guests arrive at the same time and cannot be moved once seated.

Comment: A first thought is persons as graph nodes, willing to be seated together an edge. Then trying to get cliques matching to the number of seats in a table, or checking number of independent sets compared to number of tables. Another idea is to make tables as nodes also of the 2nd set in a bi-partite graph each with degree= no of seats and then find a way that all complete a clique (connecting with nodes from the other side)

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, it’s NP-hard. Check keywords like “graph partitioning” and “max uncut”.

Comment: If they all arrive at the same time then “cannot be moved once seated” is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you optimising “sits next to” or “sits at the same table”?